# How to add text to inactive buttons in the bottom menu?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I use `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` for the bottom menu design.
My code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:title="@string/title_search"/>
    ...
</menu>
```

I want the button titles to show under all buttons but only show under the selected one.
Perhaps there is a separate function for this?

Comment: You can use app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" directly in <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView />

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.